# Who did Shalshelet Hakabblah think Onkelos was?

Tags: history, conversion-to-judaism, targumin

Rabbi Gedalyah Ibn Yechiyah in Shalshelet Hakabbah [wrote](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&pgnum=255):

> "In the fourth year of the previously mentioned emperor [Trayatzo (/Trajan?)]...there was a noble priest called Eccasia [אכקזיה] and in my opinion, this is Onkelos the Convert, who greatly loved a Jewish woman in the Punic (?) city of Isula and converted and took her as his wife and translated [the Torah] into the Greek language..."

I don't know if I properly translated the text, but does anyone know who this Eccasia/אכקזיה was that the S"H identifies with Onkelos?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the Chida considered Shalsheles HaKaballah to be a very unreliable sefer.

Comment: @N.T. I don't think we need the Chida for that. Nonetheless, I would like to understand who he was referring to.